# How to access data from the external JSON file to use in the javascript file, no JQuery, in notepad

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an external json file and I would like to access the data from it in my javascript file or my html file. I've tried looking at other solutions but its not working, I don't have jQuery so please don't include it.

What I would like for this to do is load the json file and then display the contents on the web page.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
 xobj.open('GET', 'PATIENT5.json', true); 
 xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
 callback(xobj.responseText);
 }
 };
 xobj.send(null); 
 }
function callback(data)
```

{console.log(data);
}

```
PATIENT5.json
["Harry","35"]
```

I tried adding the console.log(data); but when I checked the console there wasn't anything there. Anything would be helpful this is my first time using javascript/html! Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but try adding this: `function test(data){ console.log(data); } loadJSON(test);` and see if the console shows the data you are looking for. If that helps, update your question to give other answerers some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code with script tag. and call the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function loadJSON(file, callback) {
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
 xobj.open('GET', file, true); 
 xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
 callback(xobj.responseText);
 }
 };
 xobj.send(null); 
 }

//usage:
loadJSON("file.json", function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!